How can I reset Visual Studio Code to give me useful debug information?
I am writing a c++ program inside Visual Studio Code IDE to simulate particles moving in 2D space. My project compiles and runs fine, but I have an issue with my debugger not giving the information I need. I use g++ for compiling and gdb for debugging.
As a reproductible example, I have below in the Main.cpp file that I build and debug from
//Standard libraries
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

//namespaces
using namespace std;

int main() {

   

   //store a list of numbers between 0 and 5 in a shared pointer

    shared_ptr<double[]> numbers(new double[6]
{0,1,2,3,4,5});

   //print the numbers

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
       cout << numbers[i] << endl;
   }

   return 0;

}

If I put a break point on the line return 0, I would expect to see in my debug window the numbers variable and be able to navigate its simple contents. However, I get the following information, which is not informative to me at all:

I tried to make changes to launch.json, task.json, as I understand these have something to do with the debugger. This did not resolve my issue.
As suggested by starball, I am using the following tools:

VS Code: 1.94.2
gcc: 13.2.0
operating system:Windows 11


"My apologies as I am unable to provide a replicable example of my issue" please try your best. I think you can. (see [mre]). even a failed attempt at a MRE here could be better than nothing. also provide version info for all your tools: VS Code, cpptools, g++, gdb, and operating system.

Hello starball, thank you for contributing. When you mention a MRE, how would I do this? My issue is that my debugging window does not give useful information on the variables in scope. I can not provide an example of what I expect to see. What I can do is provide a simple code with some variables defined in main(), and show what this gives in my debug window. Will provide the requested version info.

have you experimented with a fixed-size array, or using std::array in the shared_ptr? I don't see a point from the example code of dynamic allocation. and I can understand why gdb wouldn't show you array elements, given that it was a dynamically allocated "raw" array. also, what do you mean by "reset"? was it doing what you expected before you did an update of something?

Hello starball,
Indeed, before I updated various things (c++ version, boost, moved from mingw to scoop, g++, gdb, boost, I was able to click on the variables (under local on my picture) and get sensible information.
I tried to inspect during debugging a fixed-size array and indeed, this gives me information about the contents. However, most of objects I have created in my project are as you describe dynamically allocated, and I was able to inspect their entire contents in a similar way as now I can only do with fixed-size arrays.  Wonder if this is due to updated tools.

do you remember what the version were of all the tools before you upgraded?

there are workarounds with the gdb print command, or the watch window in https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/172 and https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/688 (which I have tested- they work as workarounds), and I could write up an answer post about those, but I really want to know why/how this used to work for you before updating.
