Display dynamic array in vscode c++
there is a problem, I threw in a simple code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size = 10;
    int* arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}

I use gdb debugger but it doesn't seem to print the whole array, only the value of the first element:

Of course I read and understood that it turns out that you can simply write something like arr, 10 in the debug console and all the elements will be displayed, but this is not very convenient, especially when the array is not one-dimensional.
Tell me, is there any way to display this unfortunate array in the "variables" window?
I tried to install lldb but either my hands are crooked or it also suffers from the same problem and my task was not solved

2 Points (1) The debugger does not know the length of the array (you need to tell it as you have shown). So when does it stop outputting ints? (2) int* arr is not a pointer to array but a pointer to a single element ie pointer to int, so the debugger outputting a single value is reasonable.

A side note: in C++ it's better to avoid raw C arrays, and manual new (you already have a leak in your code due to a missing matching delete[]). Use std::vector (or std::array for fixed size) instead.

Use std::vector<int> instead. It will produce a nice, human-readaable output of all elements in the vector.

This question explains very nicely the principal reason to prefer std::vector over a dynamic array, Pointers are not arrays, and the debugger cannot tell the difference.

Sidenote: Your code is missing the inclusion of a header file for rand.

potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/79083384/11107541
